# How to use ConvertRecord and CSVRecordSetWriter to output header (with no data) in Apache NiFi?

Tags: csv, apache-nifi

I'm working with Apache NiFi to pull data from a database table and use the `ConvertRecord` to change the fetched records from avro to CSV file using `AvroReader` and `CSVRecordSetWriter`.

My process works fine when at least one row comes back from the database.

However, when the `ExecuteSQL` processor outputs a FlowFile containing 0 records (the FlowFile still contains the metadata/avro schema) - `ConvertRecord` gives me a 0-byte FlowFile output. My settings in the `CSVRecordSetWriter` service are set to output the header.

Is there a way to have `ConvertRecord` output a FlowFile that contains just the the header line in this circumstance?

Comment: One question: ExecuteSQL -> CovertRecord is good but can you use `QueryDatabaseRecord` instead since that combines both of them together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ExecuteSql Processor adds **executesql.row.count**`(Contains the number of rows returned in the select query)` attribute to the flow.

You can check value of the `attribute(executesql.row.count)` and take decision do we need to use **ConvertRecord** processor or not.

***Flow:***

```
Executesql(success)--> RouteOnAttribute(add new property ${executesql.row.count:equals(0)}) 
     --> matched --> ReplaceText //Add Header
     --> unmatched --> ConvertRecord //convert to csv format
```

if **matched** then use **ReplaceText processor** to overwrite the existing flowfile **content with header.**

if **Unmatched** that means you are **having some rows of data**  in the flowfile content so use **ConvertRecord processor** and prepare csv data.

Comment: This same capability will be offered as a property in ConvertRecord in NiFi 1.8.0 (via NIFI-5382).

Comment: @mattyb I was looking at that but it wasn't 100% clear if it would get that header to populate

Comment: I considered an approach like that, I wanted to keep things closer to the query (as I have many of these in a template situation); As a kind of 'workaround' I ended up using a UNION SELECT null as 'Foo' pattern, and then doing a regex replace with `ReplaceText`. A little extra work but seems to work. I look forward to 1.8.0 to see if that simplifies this.

Comment: @Shu when you say "content with header" are you saying the replacement text is a static string of the header, or is there some slick way to extrapolate the Avro schema metadata into the CSV compliant delimited format?

Comment: @thinice one way is using Static string of the header (or) another way is to use **ExtractAvroMetaData processor** and extract **avro.schema** from the avro data file then use ReplaceText the content of flowfile with  **avro.schema** value. The second way is dynamic based on the avro data file's avro.schema **Metadata Keys**