# Write header line for empty CSVs using Apache Nifis "CsvRecordSetWriter" Controller and "ConvertRecord" Processor

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm using NiFi 1.11.4 to read CSV files from an SFTP, do a few transformations and then drop them off on GCS. Some of the files contain no content, only a header line. During my transformations I convert the files to the AVRO format, but when converting back to CSV no file output is produced for the files where the content is empty.

I have the following settings for the Processor:
[image]

And for the Controller:
[image: CSVRecordSetWriter Settings]
[image]

I did find the following topic: [How to use ConvertRecord and CSVRecordSetWriter to output header (with no data) in Apache NiFi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52321709/how-to-use-convertrecord-and-csvrecordsetwriter-to-output-header-with-no-data) but in the comments it mentions explicitly that ConvertRecord should cover this since 1.8. Sadly I understood it incorrectly, it does not seem to work or my setup is wrong.

While I could make it work with by explicitly writing the schema as a line to empty files, I wanted to know if there is also a more elegant way?

Comment: Are there any specific requirements for CSV-AVRO-CSV transformation?

Comment: You can use `CountText => RouteOnAttribute (only_header_line : ${text.line.count:equals(1)}` to filter only headerline FF.

Comment: The CSV -> AVRO -> CSV transformation is required because I need to hash two columns. The only way I found was with a custom processor that requires AVRO as input format.
I used a workaround as you described to get around the problem, but by the other SO thread I posted was under the impression, that there should be a "better/cleaner" solution?